# How can I configure webpack's automatic code splitting to load modules relative to the build output folder?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm using Webpack 2's automatic code splitting to divide up my application into multiple output files. My `webpack.config.js` file is:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  }
}
```

This correctly builds my `app.js` file into the `build` folder along with the other module files. The build directory has the following files:

```
main.js
0.js
```

My issue is that when `main.js` requests `0.js`, it does so at the root of my application, rather than relative to its current location. So it's basically trying to load `localhost:8000/0.js` when it should be loading `localhost:8000/build/0.js`. How can I configure my project so that my project correctly loads split modules relative to my main entry point's path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Webpack will load modules from the root directory. You can configure what folder Webpack will load from by declaring the `__webpack_public_path__` variable in your entry point. So, for this scenario, you could use:

```
__webpack_public_path__ = 'build/';
```

Webpack will then load modules from the `build` folder. However this is still relative to the root. In order to tell Webpack to load scripts relative to the entry point, you can dynamically configure `__webpack_public_path__` to the directory of your entry point script with:

```
const scriptURL = document.currentScript.src;
__webpack_public_path__ = scriptURL.slice(0, scriptURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

`document.currentScript` is [well supported in evergreen browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=document-currentscript), but is not supported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: This worked great. For an IE alternative to document.currentScript i'd recommend using `document.querySelector('script[src$="nameofmyapp.js"]').src`